# React Error : Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, axios

QUESTION:

I am working on a react program which uses axios to get data from a rest api, but when I run the code it gives an error 'Cannot read property 'map' of undefined' on the browser. Please help me resolve this error.

CODE:

```
import React from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class UserList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => {
        const users = res.data;
        this.setState({ users });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.state.users.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It's because the initial value of users state is undefined. Set initial state of users to an empty array.

Comment: you are setting users and trying to access persons that will never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to `users` property no set in the `state` object.

To fix just set`users` property in state

```
state = {
  users: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initial states is incorrect, should be:

```
state = {
    users: []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not populating persons array after fetching data.

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => {
        const users = res.data;
        this.setState({ persons: users });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
```

Comment: if persons already exist in state `this.state.persons.map` never shows error bro!

Comment: You're absolutely right, persons is already defined as empty array

Comment: So no point to use `this.state.persons.length>0`

Answer (score 0):

**Better to do null check**

```
<ul>
{this.state.persons && this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}
</ul>
```